# Is there any code for get original Distance travelled in my car via OBDII in case of DTC Code clean-up

Tags: obd-ii, elm327

now at i use o1 31 PID to get Distance travelled but this give only Distance traveled since codes cleared-up not total travelled KM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately OBD2 does not specify any standard PIDs to get this information. That said, you might be able to gather this via vendor-specific extensions or by dropping down to a lower level (using direct CAN commands), but this is not portable between vehicles and thus discouraged.